# How can I get the class and the method that call to a static method?

Tags: java

I have `class X` and in it there is a `static` method called `doStuff()` and I have several other classes with methods that call to `doStuff()` for some reason. Is there a way for example to have a print method in `doStuff()` that prints from which methods and classes it is called ?

Comment: Please don't do this! (With possible exception of debugging, but even there testing would probably be better.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes: `new Throwable().getStackTrace()` returns array of `StackTraceElement`. Index number 1 is your caller.

Comment: +1: Or `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()`

Comment: Thanks, but the index I used was 3. Index 1 gives me the name of the class A and the doStuff().

Answer (score 2):

```
/**
 * <li> 0 dumpThreads
 * <li> 1 getStackTrace
 * <li> 2 getCallingMethodName
 * <li> 3 [calling method]
 * 
 * @return
 */
private String getCallingMethodName() {
    return Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3].getMethodName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the caller class using:

```
package test;

class TestCaller {
    public static void meth() {
        System.out.println("Called by class: " + sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(2));
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestCaller.meth();
    }
}
```

Output: "Called by class: class test.Main"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to **force** an `Exception` in order to do this. Check this similar question:

[Is there a way to dump a stack trace without throwing an exception in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/944991/is-there-a-way-to-dump-a-stack-trace-without-throwing-an-exception-in-java)