# Getting Clojure Stacktrace

Tags: clojure

I am aware of http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.stacktrace-api.html .

Is there a way to get the current stacktrace w/o throwing an exception and catching it?

(I'm debugging a piece of code, and want to capture stacktraces at certain points so I can analyze what's going on.)

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944991/is-there-a-way-to-dump-a-stack-trace-without-throwing-an-exception-in-java

Comment: So basically: either create your own exception, or call a function which creates its own exception? I didn't realize exceptions were such low level / inexpensive primitives. I thought surely there must be some overheat that can be eliminated if I just want the stacktrace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use clojure.repl.pst

```
user=> (try (/ 1 0) (catch Exception e (pst e)))
ArithmeticException Divide by zero
    clojure.lang.Numbers.divide (Numbers.java:156)
    clojure.lang.Numbers.divide (Numbers.java:3691)
    user/eval28 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:8)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6511)
    clojure.lang.Compiler.eval (Compiler.java:6477)
    clojure.core/eval (core.clj:2797)
    clojure.main/repl/read-eval-print--6569 (main.clj:245)
    clojure.main/repl/fn--6574 (main.clj:266)
    clojure.main/repl (main.clj:266)
    clojure.main/repl-opt (main.clj:332)
    clojure.main/main (main.clj:427)
    clojure.lang.Var.invoke (Var.java:423)
```

Comment: BTW: pst print stack trace to `*err*`

Answer (score 1):

This code return StackTraceElement array which is not so hard to [turn in readable form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149703/stacktrace-to-string-in-java):

```
(.getStackTrace (Thread/currentThread))
```