# Way to see the system.out.print origin in Eclipse's console?

Tags: eclipse, system.out

There is a way to see System.out.print origen in the console of Eclipse? I feel lost with some many outputs.

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what you are looking for or what the problem is?

Comment: If you use a Logging library like log4j it can be configured to do this

Comment: @WPrecht-AB3RY I wanna see class and line number from the System.out.print output in the console or something like that.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_patternlayout.htm

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437019/include-filename-line-number-corresponding-to-system-out-print-statements-in-ecl