# How to show line number in eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible to show corresponding code line number in `eclipse console`? I have been using chrome's `console` for `javascript` and found this feature very helpful in debugging. As an example:

**HelloWorld.java:**

```
23    System.out.println("Hello World!");
```

**Console:**

```
Hello World!                                             HelloWorld.java:23
```

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437019/include-filename-line-number-corresponding-to-system-out-print-statements-in-ecl

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include filename/line number corresponding to System.out.print statements in Eclipse Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437019/include-filename-line-number-corresponding-to-system-out-print-statements-in-ecl)