# How to throw an exception without terminating the program

Tags: java, exception

every time I throw an exception, my program terminates. Is there a way to throw an exception without terminating it? The reason why I'd want to do it is for testing purposes. In my final product, I will simply print error messages, but I have a lot of classes and exceptions help me see where "errors" are. I throw exceptions sometimes when I want to know if a condition was filled, but isn't necessarily program breaking, meaning that the program could go on after throwing the exception.

Comment: Why do you want to do this with an exception?

Comment: No, You can't throw exception and your program still running.

Comment: I said in the program description that I like exceptions because they give the line number of the error

Comment: And what user77... claims is total nonsense.

Comment: [You can print a stack trace without throwing an exception.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/944991/is-there-a-way-to-dump-a-stack-trace-without-throwing-an-exception-in-java)

Comment: Oh interesting user23, that's really helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [`try catch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) instead of `throws`:

```
try{
     //statements that may cause an exception
}
//Replace exception(type) with the exception you could be throwing
catch (exception(type) e)‏{ //Example for exception(type) is IOException
     //error handling code
     //e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @DanL no problem :) I'm happy to help!